# What was the significance of the change of garments in Leviticus 16?

Tags: law, leviticus

We are told that when Aaron entered the holy of holies to do his ministry he wore linen clothing

Leviticus 16:4 NIV

> 4 He is to put on the ***sacred linen tunic***, with linen undergarments next to his body; he is to tie the linen sash around him and put on the linen turban. These are sacred garments; so he must bathe himself with water before he puts them on.

After having done his ministry in the holy of holies Aaron is said to change his garments to continue his ministry in the courtyard

Leviticus 16:23 NIV

> “Then Aaron is to go into the tent of meeting and take off the linen garments he put on before he entered the Most Holy Place, and he is to leave them there.24 He shall bathe himself with water in the sanctuary area and put on his regular garments. Then he shall come out and sacrifice the burnt offering for himself and the burnt offering for the people, to make atonement for himself and for the people.

Was there something significant about Aaron's change of garments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What was the significance of the change of garments in Leviticus 16?

In the topic of "[High Priest](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200002023#h=12)" in the *Insight on the Scriptures*, these garments are regarded as special to certain occasions:

> Besides wearing linen garments similar to those of the underpriests in his usual activities, **the high priest wore special garments of glory and beauty on certain occasions.** [Exodus chapters 28](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002023/27/0) and [39](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002023/28/0) describe both the design and the making of these garments under the direction of Moses as commanded by God. The innermost garment (except for the *linen drawers* reaching “from the hips and to the thighs,” worn by all the priests “to cover the naked flesh”; [Ex 28:42](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002023/29/0)) was the *robe* (Heb., *kut·toʹneth*), made of fine (probably white) linen of checkerwork weave. This robe apparently had long sleeves and reached down to the ankles. It was likely woven in one piece. A sash of fine twisted linen woven with blue, reddish purple, and coccus scarlet thread went around the body, probably above the waist.​—[Ex 28:39;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002023/30/0) [39:29](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002023/30/1). [bold mine]

[Further on in this topic](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200002023#h=18) is mentioned the other times in which the high priest would were these garments:

> These beautiful garments were worn by the high priest when he approached Jehovah with an inquiry on an important matter. ([Nu 27:21;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002023/44/0) [Jg 1:1;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002023/44/1) [20:18,](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002023/44/2) [27, 28](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002023/44/3)) Also, on the Day of Atonement, after the sin offerings were completed, he changed from the white linen garments to his garments of glory and beauty. ([Le 16:23, 24](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200002023/45/0)) He apparently wore the latter on other occasions as well.

As the topic mentions, these garments were only worn when the high priest was to come near to the Ark or was making an inquiry to Jehovah. These would be most sacred times and, as arranged by Jehovah God himself, required sacred garments.

[All scripture quotations from the [*New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures* (Study Edition)](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/)]